# WCAG - what is the different between Meaningful Sequence and Focus Order?

Tags: wcag, wcag2.0

I feel confused, as these 2 seems describe the same thing?

[Level A − WCAG 2.0 Success Criterion 1.3.2 − Meaningful Sequence](https://www.ogcio.gov.hk/en/our_work/community/web_mobileapp_accessibility/promulgating_resources/handbook/wcag2a/8_6_meaningful_sequence.html)
If the content needs to be read in a certain order to make sense, ensure the webpage is written/coded in a way which indicates this order.

[Level A − WCAG 2.0 Success Criterion 2.4.3 − Focus Order](https://www.ogcio.gov.hk/en/our_work/community/web_mobileapp_accessibility/promulgating_resources/handbook/wcag2a/8_17_focus_order.html)
When writing the HTML code for a webpage, make sure the content is coded in a logical order. It will then be communicated in a logical manner when read by screen readers. This is particularly important for web forms.

Answer (score 3):

2.4.3 has to do with the tabbing order as you use <kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate through the page.  It applies to interactive elements.

> If a Web page can be navigated sequentially and the navigation sequences affect meaning or operation, **focusable components** receive focus in an order that preserves meaning and operability.

(Emphasis mine)

1.3.2 applies to the entire page - all interactive elements **and** text.  A screen reader user can navigate the entire DOM (*) using the up/down arrow keys.  The order of the DOM is the order the screen reader user will hear the elements.  If you use CSS to move elements around, say displaying an element at the bottom of the page even though it's near the top of the DOM, and if moving that element to the bottom of the page affects the meaning, then 1.3.2 would apply.

(*) It's not really the DOM they're navigating, it's the [accessibility tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.2/#dfn-accessibility-tree).  You can "hide" elements in your DOM (eg, with [`aria-hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden)) that prevent the element from appearing on the accessibility tree, but for conceptual purposes, you can think of the accessibility tree as a parallel structure to the DOM.